# How to filter an array between 2 values using NSpredicate in objective c ? I want to filter an array via name or version

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

```
(void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText

    {

        NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate 
    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd]%@" ,searchText];

        self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.devices 
    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

where self.device log is:::

Array is,

```
 (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa32caab60> (entity: Device; id: 
0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://7EE6EBA4-6F15-49D8-B994-2E02379A75CD
/Device/p2> ; data: {\n    company = c1;\n    name = apple;\n    version = 
v1;\n})",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa32cb4100> (entity: Device; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://7EE6EBA4-6F15-49D8-B994-2E02379A75CD/Device/p3> ; data: {\n    company = \"com 2\";\n    name = asad;\n    version = v2;\n})",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa32cb4160> (entity: Device; id: 
0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://7EE6EBA4-6F15-49D8-B994-2E02379A75CD
/Device/p4> ; data: {\n    company = \"company 3\";\n    name = abbas;\n 
   version = v3;\n})",

    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa32ca8810> (entity: Device; id: 
0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://7EE6EBA4-6F15-49D8-B994-2E02379A75CD
/Device/p5> ; data: {\n    company = ccc;\n    name = pakistan;\n    version
 = vvv;\n})",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa32ca8870> (entity: Device; id: 
0xd000000000180000 <x-coredata://7EE6EBA4-6F15-49D8-B994-2E02379A75CD
/Device/p6> ; data: {\n    company = bbyiww;\n    name = pine;\n    version 
= vvvrre;\n})"
)
```

Comment: Please be more specific and format your question properly.

Comment: You can use 'AND' or 'OR' keywords as per the requirements.

Comment: I have tried everything but can't find desired output. I had tried @"(SELF.name contains[cd]%@ OR SELF.version contains[cd]%@)". But it then crashes ? Any sample code.Thank you Vijay Masiwal

Comment: Its the core data ouput and I just copied it as LOG. Have some idea about my question ? Libran Coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(value1 != 0) AND (value2 == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

OR

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value1 contains[cd] %@ OR value2 contains[cd] %@", value1, value2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your predicate like this

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd]%@ and SELF.version = %@" ,searchText, versionNo];

self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.devices filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```